# Strange sound when combining sin waves

Tags: python, audio

After using `wave` file to generate a single sin wave, I tried to generate simple chords by adding sin waves together as the code below. But it sounds very strange. It sounds like a sin wave that is sometimes loud and sometimes quiet.

Calculate using Product-to-sum and sum-to-product identities also proves this:
sin(ax)+sin(bx)=2sin((a+b)x)cos((a-b)x),
where sin((a+b)x) makes it sound like a sin wave and cos((a-b)x) makes it sometimes loud and sometimes quiet.

How to avoid this phenomenon?

```py
import wave
import array
from math import *

NC = 1
SW = 2
FR = 48000
NF = 48000
FP = "basic.wav"
DT = array.array("h", bytes(NF*SW))

A = 440 * (2*pi/FR)
C = A * 2**(-9/12)
E = A * 2**(-5/12)
G = A * 2**(-2/12) # Typo; After modifying the phenomenon still exists

for i in range(NF):
    DT[i] += int(8192 * sin(i * C))
    DT[i] += int(8192 * sin(i * E))
    DT[i] += int(8192 * sin(i * G))

f = wave.open(FP, "wb")
f.setnchannels(NC)
f.setsampwidth(SW)
f.setframerate(FR)
f.writeframes(DT.tobytes())
f.close()
```

Comment: You're probably hearing an acoustical [beat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)) tone which is an interference pattern between two sounds of slightly different frequencies.

Comment: Partly I think it's not sounding correct because your `G` should be `G = A * 2 **(-2/12)`. With the G# it makes a C+ (augmented) chord, rather than a CMaj.

Your code works ok and sounds fine to me, so it could perhaps also be some distortion in your audio system?